# Xsocket Unrecognized Guid format

Tags: c#, format, guid, xsockets.net

I used xsockets for a while and i get following message very frequency.

```
System.FormatException: Unrecognized Guid format.
   at System.Guid.GuidResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument, String failureArgumentName, Exception innerException)
   at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags, GuidResult& result)
   at System.Guid.Parse(String input)
   at XSockets.Protocol.XSocketProtocol.<>c__DisplayClass22.<Heartbeat>b__1f(Object o, ControlArgs args)
   at XSockets.Protocol.XSocketProtocol.<SetFrameHandler>b__b(IList`1 payload, FrameType op)
```

Is there any problem with those things?

update:

When i remove the following code, no exception is throw.

```
public override void OnOpened()
{
    this.ProtocolInstance.Heartbeat(notifyAction: (reason) => { Console.WriteLine("Heart beat :" +  reason); });
}
```

Comment: are you trying to convert a string variable to numeric data type in your code?

Comment: I catch all exception in my code but got nothing. It's something relative with XSocket Hearthbeat.

Comment: actually it is the improper parsing which is not allowing the further process to take place. Can you post your code snippet

Comment: What version of xsockets are you using?

Comment: @Uffe i'm using xsockets 4.

Comment: @Akansha It's a complex code and i'm finding which method throwing this exception.

Comment: Are you assigning Guid somewhere in your code?

Comment: I can take a look at it if you send me the code for your heartbeat functionality. Uffe at xsockets.net is my email